# Java Applet on Linux unable to gain Permissions

Tags: java, permissions

I'm taking an online class and I'm occasionally getting hung-up because the class is semi windows-centric.  Currently I've got a java applet in which I'm trying to play an audio clip with.  I'm using Idea Intellij and I've put an audio file in the same location as the class files.  I've also updated the policy file that idea uses to run the applet, but no matter what I do, it can't seem to find the audio file.  I'm 75% sure it's something I've not figured out with the policy file (argh!), but I can't figure out what that is.  I'll paste in a code snippet, my policy file and some output from when I try to run it.  Please help - this is the second time I've been stuck due to linux-specific differences.

Apologies for the formatting hiccups...

```
    public class MyApplet extends JApplet implements ActionListener
    {
        JButton play, stop;
        AudioClip audioClip;
        File myAudioFile;

        public void init()
        {
            play = new JButton("Play");
            play.addActionListener(this);

            stop = new JButton("Stop");
            stop.addActionListener(this
    [...took out unnecessary stuff...]
            System.out.println("Codebase is: " + getCodeBase());
            myAudioFile = new File(getCodeBase().toString()+"desktop-login.ogg");
            if(myAudioFile.exists()) {
                audioClip = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "desktop-login.ogg");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Failed to find file:"+ audioClip);
            }

        }
[...took out unnecessary stuff...]
    //------------------POLICY FILE CONTENTS--
    grant {
      permission java.security.AllPermission;
      permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "accept, connect, listen, resolve";
    };

    grant codeBase "file:/home/mylogin/IdeaProjects/3RD/Lesson7/soundPlay/out/production/soundPlay/*" {
      permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.home", "read";
    }; 

    //--------output (scrubbed a bit - it's failing at the audio clip play part because the audioClip object is null): 
    Codebase is: file:/home/mylogin/IdeaProjects/3RD/Lesson7/soundPlay/out/production/soundPlay/
    Failed to find file:null
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at MyApplet.actionPerformed(MyApplet.java:48)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
```

Answer (score 0):

use file path like this and try

```
file:////home/mylogin/IdeaProjects/3RD/Lesson7/soundPlay/out/production/soundPlay/
```

Comment: That's not going to work.  Basically this line is where the problem is: audioClip = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "desktop-login.ogg");  I think due to permissions, it's not finding the file.  It just returns: "Failed to find file:sun.applet.AppletAudioClip@b179c3"

Comment: I had a similar kind of problem when use file location as a uri so that I changed it in this way and it worked for both windows and linux file:///<windows or linux file path>. May be your case is different.

Comment: I supposed if there is a way I can convert what I get back from getCodeBase and turn it into a proper URI as you've indicated that may work.   I think there's got to be a more elegant solution though - I'm still thinking it's a permissions issue with my policy file...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I feel silly.  Turns out trying to load .ogg files in native java on linux doesn't work.  I had thought it was going to use Linux based codecs, but I was wrong.  It was going to use what java can decode natively - which is for example, .wav files.  When I switched to .wav files everything was happy and started to work.  Sheesh!